# Manual update of SwiftUI View

Tags: ios, swift, data-binding, swiftui

Traditionally, a SwiftUI application will automatically update its view in response to any state changes. This occurs when the @State propertyWrapper detects any updates. I'm curious, is it possible to *manually* redraw a SwiftUI View, instead of relying on the @State data binding technique ?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: SwiftUI is using the MVVM Pattern and not MVC. In MVVM the ViewModel is responsible for redrawing the view. Changing the ViewModel will therefore redraw the view.

Comment: @Sweeper I'd like to use SwiftUI as a rendering layer for a higher-level framework. So I'd like to regenerate a new View on each event, diff it with the old view, and redraw manually.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use an `ObservableObject` object as model and then call `objectWillChange.send()` to trigger a refresh

```swift
struct MyView : View {
    @ObservedObject var model: Model
    var body: some View { .. }
}

class Model: ObservableObject { 
    func reloadView() {
        objectWillChange.send()
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this makes Sorin's great answer a little easier to understand.

1 — Place this in your Extensions.swift (or anywhere, really)

```
class ReloadViewHelper: ObservableObject {
    func reloadView() {
        objectWillChange.send()
    }
}
```

2 — Then in the class that didn't update, add this variable.

```
@ObservedObject var reloadViewHelper = ReloadViewHelper()
```

3 — Then when You want your whole view to update, just call:

```
reloadViewHelper.reloadView()
```

Or like this

```
Button(action: { reloadViewHelper.reloadView() } ) {
    Text("Update View")
}
```

Comment: `ObservedObject` is for passing `ObservableObject`s around not initializing.